# Plot the inequality in R

Tags: r, plot, inequality

I would like to plot the inequality x3 <= sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2).  My problem is, since the sqrt returns only principal square roots, only half part of the graph is plotted.  I used the below code.

```
x1=x2=seq(-20,20,length=100);
x3=seq(-30,30,length=100);
df = expand.grid(x1=x1,x2=x2,x3=x3)
df$ind = with(df,x3 <= sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2) | x3 >= -sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2))
plot3d(df$x1,df$x2,df$x3,type='n')
with(df[df$ind, ], points3d(x, y, z, color = 'blue', size = 2))
```

But it is not working as I expected. It should plot a second order cone in R^3.

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
df$ind = with(df,x3 <= sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2) | x3 >= -sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2))
```

is always true as it is equivalent of

```
X = x1^2 + x2^2
df$ind = with(df,x3 <= X | x3 >= -X)
```

but X is always non negative, so each positive x3 is >= -X and each negative is <=X.

it should be rather

```
df$ind = with(df,x3^2 <= x1^2 + x2^2)
```

which is a valid inequality for the cone (no sqrt is required!)

or, if you want to follow your original idea, you have to make sure that both subconditions are checked for valid x3 values (positive/negative):

```
df$ind = with(df,
              (x3>0  & x3 <=  sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2)) |
              (x3<=0 & x3 >= -sqrt(x1^2 + x2^2))
             )
```